# Trouble disabling a text field based on dropdown selection (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with a dropdown menu followed by a text input field. The input box is disabled by default. Selecting a specified option from the menu should enable the text field.

I did some research and found many similar problems, however none of the solutions seem to be working. I tried a very simple code on jsfiddle to see if it's the solution itself that's the problem, or my code in particular.. My original code did not work, and neither did the simplified version. Here is the simplified code sample:

HTML:

```
<select id="menu" onChange="checkOption()">
    <option value="A">Option A</option>
    <option value="B">Option B</option>
    <option value="C">Option C</option>
    <option value="D">Option D</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="input" disabled>
```

JavaScript:

```
function checkOption() {
    if(document.getElementById("menu").value != "A") {
        document.getElementById("input").disable = 'false';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("input").disable = 'true';
    }
}
```

The text box remains disabled no matter what I click. I tried removing the default disable, and still no luck. I also tried various other solutions, however this was the most straightforward which is why I don't understand why it's not working.

It's probably something really obvious that I'm not seeing... I'm very very new at this, so if anyone would care to shed some light on my problem, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `disabled` not `disable`

```
document.getElementById("input").disabled = true;
```

You can also clean the code up by passing `this` into your handler and referencing that (also no need for the `if, else` - just `disable` based on a condition directly:

```
<select id="menu" onChange="checkOption(this)">

function checkOption(obj) {
    var input = document.getElementById("input");
    input.disabled = obj.value == "A";
}
```

Aaaaand a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/23EpC/

Comment: Also the values need to be real booleans, not strings (as you're probably typing even now :)

Comment: @Pointy -- Yep - also did some refactoring while I was in there :D

Comment: @tymeJv I tried with both disable and disabled (different solutions used both for some reason) and still neither worked.

Comment: @Laya302 that's because you're setting the flag to non-empty strings, so `"false"` is just as `true` as `"true"` - you have to set the flag to a boolean value.

Comment: @Pointy What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Laya302-- `disabled` takes a boolean (`true` or `false`) the string `"true"` is not the same as `true`

Comment: @Pointy you mean instead of `'false'`, I should remove the `'`?

Comment: @Laya302 there's a big difference between the constant `false` and the string `"false"` - the "disabled" flag has a boolean value, and in JavaScript any non-empty string is `true`.

Comment: @Pointy I tried `document.getElementById("input").disable = true;` but it did not work, if that's what you mean?

Comment: :O I see now what you did, but I don't get why mine didn't work :S

Comment: You had `disable` which isn't a command - and you were quoting your booleans which converted them to strings.

Comment: @tymeJV I did put `disabled` in jsfiddle, I just copy pasted from my original question above into this comment which is why it says `disable`, sorry about that

Comment: @Laya302 if you have a jsfiddle that *doesn't* work, you should post a link to it.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks, I'll do that next time. It's working just fine now!